# Why alternate row color is skipping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table and I am trying to make the alternate row colors by using the following expression:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!LastName.Value,COUNTDISTINCT,NOTHING) MOD 2 = 0
,IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=0,"#BED2F0","White")
,IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=1,"White","#BED2F0"))
```

But what is happening is, it sometime highlights two rows while skipping 2 rows...

Here is the output:

[image]

As you can see, there is `blue, white, blue, white, white`, Why isn't it highlighting the correct row?

Also, I am able to enter the expression per textbox in the row but not the row as a whole. How can I select the entire row and change the color?

Comment: Do you have people with the same last name?  As for the second part, highlight the row, then press F4 to bring up the properties for that row.  You should be able to to paste the expression in there.

Comment: They are all different last name and thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully, these two expressions produce identical result:

```
IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=0,"#BED2F0","White")
IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=1,"White","#BED2F0")
```

Not sure why you have that but you can replace that whole expression:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!LastName.Value,COUNTDISTINCT,NOTHING) MOD 2 = 0
,IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=0,"#BED2F0","White")
,IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=1,"White","#BED2F0"))
```

with this:

```
=IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=0,"#BED2F0","White")
```

Comment: Did you try replacing your long expression with the one line in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I took your advice